# How to create new Excel from another Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I am trying to take data from a spreadsheet that gives me the first and last names of people in my office, but I am new to scripting and PowerShell, so I am utterly clueless on how to do this. I want the new spreadsheet to print the emails as so:

lastnamef@company.com

I looked at similar examples, but since I am so new to this, I am unsure on how to turn that into mine, but nevertheless, here is what I have (almost identical to the last example I looked at on here):

```
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 116 
$startRow,$col=2,1 

$excel=new-object -com excel.application
$wb=$excel.workbooks.open("Libraries\Documents\Emails for UAC.xls")

for ($i=1; $i -le $wb.sheets.count; $i++){
    $sh=$wb.Sheets.Item($i)
    $endRow=$sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    $email=$sh.Cells.Item($startRow,$col).Value2
    $address=$sh.Cells.Item($startRow+1,$col).Address() +  +$sh.Cells.Item($endRow,$col).Address()
    $sh.Range($rangeAddress).Value2 | foreach {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{City=$city;Area=$_}
    }
}
$excel.Workbooks.Close()
Next

objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close
objExcel.Quit
```